# How to access current data and send data to another php file using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

##ajax function in the php file i need to send id,and two input field values to my updateReq.php file ##

```
function updateFunction(del,inp1,inp2){
   var ajaxRequest; 
   try{

      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){

      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {

         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){

            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
         ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
   }

   var queryString = "?del=" + del;
   queryString += "&inp1=" +inp1;
   queryString += "$inp2=" +inp2;
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "updateReq.php" + queryString, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

### in my file i use this part to access ajax function

### The ajax function and the bleow code on the same php file

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
   $display_string .= "<td><input type='text' id='inp1' name='inp1' value='$row[cname]' /></td>";
   $display_string .= "<td><input type='number' id='inp2' name='inp2' value='$row[rank]'/></td>";
   $display_string .= "<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteFunction($row[id])'>Delete?</a></td>";
   $display_string .= "<td><a href='#' onclick='updateFunction( $row[id], $row[cname] ,$row[rank])'>Update?</a></td>";
   $display_string .= "</tr>";
}
$display_string .= "</table>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

### This is my updateReq.php

```
<?php
// Retrieve data from Query String
include 'config.php';
$id = $_GET['del'];
$inp1 = $_GET['inp1'];
$inp2 = $_GET['inp2'];

// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query=mysql_query("update rcategories set cname='$inp1' rank='$inp2' where id='$id'") or die("can not update");

?>
```

Comment: where your jquery code exist ? on same file or other file ?

Comment: when you call updateFunction() ???

Comment: when i click Update link which is in php file it calls the updateFunction()

Comment: the jquery and php are in same php file

Comment: @sreetharraja So according to your code the ajax request action is the same php file where the ajax function is define ?

Comment: `queryString += "$inp2=" +inp2;` change it to `queryString += "&inp2=" +inp2;`

Comment: What is your question? Please take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code..

`queryString += "$inp2=" +inp2;` change it to `queryString += "&inp2=" +inp2;`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `queryString` you are using `$` instead of `&`